# Element '{http://www...}ResponseDetails': The type definition is abstract

Tags: php, soap, xsd, wsdl

Got following error when validating xml response against the xsd. What does this excactly means?

Answer (score 0):

It means that either the element, or the type assigned to it, has the `abstract="true"` attribute set on it. This means that you cannot use it in the XML document.

You may be able to use `xsi:type` to override the type of the element.